# JSON Data stored to SQLite

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14441382/insert-json-data-into-the-sqlite-database-in-android) to store JSON parsed data into SQLite Database, but whenever i use my app offline not getting stored data into ListView.

Is there anything left to implement in my existing code ?

**MainActivity.java:-**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        databaseHelper=new CategoryHelper(MainActivity.this);
        contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        ListView lv = getListView();

        // Listview on item click listener
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {


            }
        });

        // Calling async task to get json
        new GetContacts().execute();
    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     * */
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                        databaseHelper.saveCategoryRecord(id,name);

                        // tmp hashmap for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(contact);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME }, new int[] { R.id.name });

            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
```

Comment: When offline you want to get the data from sqlite? if yes Where did you wrote the code for retrieving the data from sqlite?

Comment: @Vamshi actually i am new and don't know how to retrieve code from sqlite to show in a List in onCreate(), will you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what that `ServiceHandler` thing is, but I'm guessing the call to `makeServiceCall()` returns null when you're offline. This means you aren't populating the `contactList`, which means it's empty when you're creating the `ListAdapter`.

I'm guessing what you want to do, is add an `else` clause to `if (jsonStr != null)` that populates `contactList` with records from your DB. How to do this depends on the implementation details of `CategoryHelper`.

Answer (score 0):

Using shared preference would be a better approach for that. Follow these steps:

search and download `GSON` library. This will simplify our task for saving and retrieving JSON to/from shared preferences and let your app use the `GSON` library

example:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("mySharedPreferenceKey");
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();

//convert your object to string and save it to shared preference
ArrayList<Integer> myIntArrs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
editor.putString("myJSONKey", new Gson().toJson(myIntArrs)).commit();

//get your json string from shared preferences
public final Type ARRAYLIST_INTEGER = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Integer>>(){}.getType(); 
ArrayList<Integer> intArrs = gson.fromJson(prefs.getString("myJSONKey", "{}"), ARRAYLIST_INTEGER);

//do something with your intArrs
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i tried many times, but not solved, can you show me the way by making changes in my existing code ?